# How can I detect the React Native packager in a module?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I have a module that I use for node and (now) react-native. I'd like to selectively export code depending on which platform it's going to run on. If you can get this to run on the device, you've solved the problem.

module:

```
if(!react_native){
    exports.fs = require('fs');
}

exports.print = function(str){ console.log(str); }
```

on device:

```
var m = require('module');
m.print("hello world.");
```

Is there any way to do this?

I don't want to create two separate modules that only differ in index.js if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple check - loading the basic package:

```
var isNative = false;
var Platform;

try {
  Platform = require('react-native').Platform;
  isNative = true;
} catch(e) {}

if (isNative) {
  console.log(Platform.OS, Platform.Version);
} else {
  console.log('node');
}
```

Comment: I don't think that works. Have you tried running it? Look at my example again, I edited it. Try require('fs') in the node only part.